# java export variable output to csv

Tags: java, file, export-to-csv

Any idea why this code not printing a blank output file??

`BufferedWriter out = new BufferedWriter(new FileWriter(new File(path)));

```
while (rs.next()) {
                        String id = rs.getString("id");
                        String title = rs.getString("title");
                        String content = rs.getString("introtext");
                        String parsed = Jsoup.parse(content).select("body").text();
                        data.add(id + " " + title + " " + parsed);
                        System.out.println(id + "\t" +title + "\t" + parsed );
                        out.write(rs.getString(id));
                        out.write(rs.getString(title));
                        out.write(rs.getString(parsed));
                    }

                rs.close();
                stmt.close();
                out.close();
            } catch (Exception e) {
                System.out.println(e);
            }
        }`
```

Comment: If `rs.next()` is returning false the first iteration then the filw would be empty. Try debugging your JDBC query

Answer (score 0):

Your output seems to be flawed, because you first fetch id, title and parsed and then attempt to write fetching those values from the query (and they probably aren't there). This

```
out.write(rs.getString(id));
out.write(rs.getString(title));
out.write(rs.getString(parsed));
```

should very probably be

```
out.write(id);
out.write(title);
out.write(parsed);
```

And you might also want to write a comma as well (between those fields).